# How to place a panel correctly into a form after being removed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I hope this is an easy task, nonetheless I need some help.

```
  SomeForm f = new SomeForm();

  if (someStatement) // relocate pnlRight onto new form f
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(pnlRight);
            f.Controls.Add(pnlRight);

            pnlRight.Location = new Point(0, 0); // I want to place pnlRight at (0, 0) on the new form f
            this.pnlRight.Visible = false;
            f.Show();
        }
  else // hide form and relocate pnlRight onto main form
        {
            this.pnlRight.Location = new Point(pnlLeft.Location.X + pnlLeft.Width + 10, pnlLeft.Location.Y);
            this.Controls.Add(pnlRight);
            this.pnlRight.Visible = true;

            frmSettings.Hide();
        }
```

So - I have a main form with two panels: pnlLeft and pnlRight. On button click (here if someStatement is true) pnlRight should be relocated on a newly created form. Works perfectly. BUT: If I relocate pnlRight again onto the main form, it is NOT placed where I want it to be, but instead at (0, 0) above pnlLeft. What's wrong? I checked both panel's properties and can't see any odds. Maybe somebody has a hint for me,

Best
Dennis

Comment: The code as you show it here will add an extra pnlRight reference to the control collection if someStatement = false. Is this actual code or just a modified-for-example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 panels in your form then you need to set the dock property of both the panels in the sequence you want to display them.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx

Particularly, "Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control relative to the upper-left corner of its container."

You tried setting its location **after** you re-added onto the form?